# Search View doesn't show result on typing first three letters

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, searchview

I'm Developing a android project on Food Ordering App and in that i made search view for searching the food so that the user can search the food and the main problem is that when I type anything in Search View Bur for Burger it does not display any result as it should display on just typing the first 2/3 words as in other apps instead i need to type full word of Burger and then it displays the same but i want to display the result below the search view when the user enters some words of the respective food

```
package com.example.menulayout

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.SearchView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore
import java.lang.StringBuilder
import java.util.*
import kotlin.collections.ArrayList

class SearchFragment : Fragment() {
    lateinit var recyclerView : RecyclerView
    lateinit var searchView : SearchView
    lateinit var foodAdapter : FoodAdapter
    private val mArrayList: ArrayList<ModelFood> = ArrayList()
    lateinit var arrayList : ArrayList<ModelFood>
    private val fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    private val fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val retview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false)
        return retview
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        searchView = view.findViewById(R.id.frag_search_view)
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(p0: String?): Boolean {
                return true
            }
            override fun onQueryTextChange(p0: String?): Boolean {
                if(p0 == ""){
                    mArrayList.clear()
                }
                else {
                    searchFoodBreakfast(p0!!.split(' ').joinToString(" ") { it.capitalize()  })
                }
                return true
            }
        })

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.frag_search_recycler_view)
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        val layoutmanager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutmanager
        foodAdapter = FoodAdapter(activity!!.applicationContext, mArrayList)
        recyclerView.adapter = foodAdapter
    }

    private fun searchFoodBreakfast(s: String) {
        fStore.collection("HotBox Admin")
            .document("F0y2F2SeaoWHjY7sIHFr4JRf1HF2")
            .collection("Breakfast")
            .whereEqualTo("foodname",s)
            .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, firebaseFirestoreException ->
                if (firebaseFirestoreException != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "No Food Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
                for (i in querySnapshot!!) {
                    val foodsearch = ModelFood(
                        i.getString("imageuri")!!,
                        i.getString("foodname")!!,
                        i.getString("foodprice")!!,
                        i.getString("foodofferprice")!!,
                        i.getString("fooddescription")!!,
                        i.getString("foodcategory")!!
                    )
                    Log.d("key", i.getString("foodname").toString())
                    mArrayList.add(foodsearch)
                }
                foodAdapter.update(mArrayList)
            }
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.hide()
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.show()
    }
}
```

FoodAdapter.kt(Adapter Class)

```
package com.example.menulayout

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.util.Log
import android.view.Display
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.*
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FieldValue
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore
import com.google.firebase.firestore.SetOptions
import java.io.Serializable
import java.util.*
import kotlin.collections.ArrayList
import kotlin.collections.HashMap

class FoodAdapter(var con: Context, var list: ArrayList<ModelFood>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<viewHolder>() {
    private val userid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid.toString()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): viewHolder {
        val layoutInflater : LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(con)
        val v : View = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_breakfast_rv, parent, false)
        return viewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list.size
    }

    fun update(list: ArrayList<ModelFood>) {
        this.list = list
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: viewHolder, position: Int) {
        val foodItem = list[position]
        Glide.with(con).load(foodItem.imageuri).centerCrop().dontAnimate().into(holder.ig_fd_image)
        holder.tv_fd_name.text = foodItem.foodname
        holder.tv_fd_price.text = foodItem.foodprice
        holder.tv_fd_offprice.text = foodItem.foodofferprice

        holder.parent_lay.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(con, ProductDetailsActivity::class.java)
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            intent.putExtra("object",foodItem)
            con.startActivity(intent)
        }

        holder.ig_fd_cart.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(con, ProductDetailsActivity::class.java)
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            intent.putExtra("object",foodItem)
            con.startActivity(intent)
        }

        holder.chk_add_fav.isChecked = foodItem.isLiked == 1
        holder.chk_add_fav.setOnCheckedChangeListener { compoundButton, b ->
            if(compoundButton.isPressed) {
                if (b) {
                    val uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
                    val favData = HashMap<String, Any>()
                    favData["foodcategory"] = foodItem.foodcategory
                    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("HotBox")
                        .document(userid)
                        .collection("Favorites")
                        .document(foodItem.foodid)
                        .set(favData, SetOptions.merge())
                        .addOnSuccessListener {
                            Toast.makeText(con, foodItem.foodname + " added to Favorites", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                            holder.chk_add_fav.isChecked = true
                        }
                        .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                            Toast.makeText(con, "Failed to Add", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                            Log.d("Main", e.toString())
                        }
                }
                else {
                    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("HotBox")
                        .document(userid)
                        .collection("Favorites")
                        .document(foodItem.foodid)
                        .delete()
                        .addOnSuccessListener {
                            Toast.makeText(con, foodItem.foodname + " removed from Favorites", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                            holder.chk_add_fav.isChecked = false
                        }
                        .addOnFailureListener {
                            Log.d("Main", it.message.toString())
                            Toast.makeText(con, foodItem.foodname + " failed to remove from Favorites", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class viewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    val parent_lay = itemView.findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.parent_rel_lay)
    val ig_fd_image = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.food_image_inside_rv)
    val chk_add_fav = itemView.findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.favorites_add_to_fav)
    val ig_fd_cart = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.image_view_add_to_cart_inside_rv)
    val tv_fd_name = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txt_food_name_inside_rv)
    val tv_fd_price = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txt_food_price_inside_rv)
    val tv_fd_offprice = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txt_food_offer_price_inside_rv)
}
```

The above is my code pls help me with it so that the user can search the food by just entering the first 2/3 letters of the food name
Thank You in Advance
Please help me guys out there!!! :):)

Comment: could u add your code for foodadapter

Comment: yes pls give me a min

Comment: Arun Abimanyu Pls check i've added FoodAdapter.kt

Comment: @KarthikIyer, Here is my two cents on your issue. It is not recommended to read from the firestore for every search. Listening to the firestore has to happen only once and those data from the firestore have to be maintained as your data model `ModelFood` in the main memory. The cause of your issue is you are asserting the exact food name with your search keyword using this firestore API `whereEqualTo`. If you had maintained the model, then you could use `contains` to check whether the substring is present or not

Comment: Okk Vaikundam Raghul let me check and I'll let u know

Comment: Hey Vaikundam Raghul could you pls give me a snippet of your answer pls

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
fStore.collection("HotBox Admin").collection("F0y2F2SeaoWHjY7sIHFr4JRf1HF2").collection("Breakfast");
                foodRef.whereArrayContains("foodname", "yourQuery").get();
```

Comment: Now also the same problem exists